# Defining relations on nested objects

Tags: jsdata

Can js-data create relations on nested objects? Here is an example:

GET /card/2

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "foo",
  "action": {     // <-- nested object
    "typeId": 1,  // foreign key to actionType.id
    "param0": 20
  }
}
```

GET /action-types

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jump",
  "paramsMeta": [{
     "name": "Distance",
     "max": 30
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Damage",
  "paramsMeta": [{
    "name": "amount",
    "min": 0
  }, {
    "name": "isRelative",
    "type": "Boolean"
  }]
}]
```

resources.js:

```
DS.defineResource({
  name: 'card',
  relations: {
    hasOne: {
      actionType: {
        localField: 'action.type',
        localKey: 'action.typeId'
      }
    }
  }
});

DS.defineResource(
  name: 'actionType',
  endpoint: 'action-types'
);
```

What I need is to initialize property `card.action.type`. But in current example property `card['action.type']` is initialized and that's not what I want. To be more specific, current `card` Object after js-data processing is:

```
> console.log(DS.get('card', 2));
>
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'foo',
  'action.type': { id: 1, name: 'Jump', ... } // <-- reference to actionType
  action: {
    typeId: 1, param0: 20
  }
}
```

But I need the structure to be like this:

```
> console.log(DS.get('card', 2));
>
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'foo',
  action: {
    typeId: 1,
    type: { id: 1, name: 'Jump', ... }, // <-- reference to actionType
    param0: 20
  }
}
```

js-data version: 2.9.0

Comment: Based on the JSON you posted, "localField" should be set to "action", not "action.type". To help you further, can you explain what "typeId" is? Is it a primary key for actions, or a foreign key to some other entity? You also need to post your resource definition for "actionType", as you've only shown one side of the relation.

Comment: Sure. I've updated the question. Now it has more details.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

You need to switch from a `hasOne` to a `belongsTo` relation, e.g.:

```
belongsTo: {
  'action-type': {
    localField: 'action.type',
    localKey: 'action.typeId'
  }
}
```

Here are two plunkers that *try* to do what you want:

js-data v2: http://plnkr.co/edit/nbZtaXZ8AZwh9ITiG1kO?p=preview (relations on nested path, doesn't work quite right)

js-data v3: http://plnkr.co/edit/Tyxsab0icCs8nn68fkta?p=preview (relations on nested path, doesn't work quite right)

Unfortunately, JSData can't create ES5 getters for a nested path like `action.type`, so the links simply don't work quite as expected. (Well is does make a getter, but it ends up being a property named `action.type`, not what you want).

#### Workaround

One workaround would be to define an intermediate "action" resource, and have
the following relationships:

- card belongsTo action
- action hasOne card
- action belongsTo actionType
- actionType hasMany action

The only caveat is the `card.action` now needs to have a primary key. The easiest
thing would be to simply make `card.action.id` equal to `card.id`.

Here are two plunkers that demonstrate this workaround:

js-data v2: http://plnkr.co/edit/cUDyP0Zmk39zP30sTVpL?p=preview (relations on nested path, solved using intermediate resource)

js-data v3: http://plnkr.co/edit/J8yNL9zIp5h9RJL9XM9w?p=preview (relations on nested path, solved using intermediate resource)

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. It seems that adding primary key is not an options because of backend restrictions and because of that the fact that some cards have more than one action (for example, card can also have `triggerAction` field or `additionalAction` field). Currently I'm trying to link `actionType` relation by hand - waiting for DS.find() promise to be resolved and than linking `actionType` object by `card.action = DS.get('actionType', action.typeId);`